# Is there a way to include face tracking in an A-Frame project?

Tags: aframe, face-api

I'm creating a web-based application that needs to have face tracking. I think A-Frame is the best option for web development, but I'm not sure if there's a way to include face tracking in the project. Would something like faceapi.js be able to be implemented into my A-Frame project? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There certainly is, I have been working with face tracking in A-Frame for the past couple of weeks (albeit a different face library). Perhaps you could elaborate on what specifically you're having trouble with, but here's the general approach:

First you need camera footage. Some libraries set up the camera for you, others you have to setup yourself. Check out my simple Glitch project for how to setup a webcam:
https://hello-webcam.glitch.me/

You can make a custom A-Frame component to manage the face tracker predictions and apply them to some 3D object. However, image processing models tend to suck up a lot of processing power. If you do everything on the main thread, you will notice that A-Frame becomes pretty choppy.

To get around this I suggest performing your face modeling on a seperate thread using a [WebWorker](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers). The webworker thread and main thread can only communicate through `"message"` events containing some payload. So the idea is that your main thread with A-Frame will fetch image data from a webcam `<video>` (perhaps writing it to a `<canvas>` in between) and send it to the web worker. The worker will run the face tracking model to make predictions. The web worker will send the prediction data back to the main thread, where the listener set up in your A-Frame component will receive that data and apply it to the scene somehow.

I've had mixed results with different libraries because web workers cannot access the DOM. Some libraries depend on `<canvas>`, others let you directly pass image data for predictions, while others use the partially supported [`OffscreenCanvas`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/OffscreenCanvas). Play around with it and see where you get stuck.

Comment: Hi do you have an example you can share on let's say placing a mustache or a nose ring etc. on a person through my phone camera?